# How do i close a old window each time a new window is oppened in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a simplified code below of 2 separate screens. How do I have it so that when one screen is opened the old one is then closed?

Whilst i don't have multiple screens in this example i would like to be able to to this for 6-9 screens dependent upon GUI design.

any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time
from tkinter import simpledialog

def login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry("530x290")
    Label(screen2, text = "please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
   
    calibration1 = StringVar()
    calibration2 = StringVar()
    calibration3 = StringVar()
   
    global calibration1_entry
    global calibration2_entry
    global calibration3_entry
   
    calibration1_entry= Entry(screen2, textvariable = calibration1).place(x=350, y=70)
    calibration2_entry = Entry(screen2, textvariable = calibration2).place(x=350, y=120)
    calibration3_entry = Entry(screen2, textvariable = calibration3).place(x=350, y=170)

def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("530x290")
    screen.title("Remote Monitoring Site 1")
    Label(text = "Remote Monitoring Site 1", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", width = "30", height = "2", command = login).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
   
    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign `screen2` to be `None` at the beginning and make sure to destroy and reopen it, if it isn't `None`:

```
def login():
    global screen2

    if screen2 is None: # if screen2 is not Toplevel
        screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    else:
        screen2.destroy() # destroy and start new screen
        screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    ...
    ...

def main_screen():
    global screen2,screen

    screen = Tk()
    screen2 = None # Assign to None at the beginning
    ...
    ...
```

This will also make sure no two `Toplevel` is open at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make more then one script for example to code login screen in one script, main menu in other, etc. Then you can use `import os` to close and open scripts. Function would be something like:

```
def login():
    if username == "admin" and password == "admin":
        file = 'python3 main_menu.py' # or you can do it
        root.destroy()                # proper way with db
        os.system(file)
```